# How to get top 10 customers based on values of orders

Tags: linq

I have a list of `Customers` who each have a list of `Orders`. Each `Order` has a list of `LineItems`.

I would like to write a LINQ query that would get me the top 10 customers based on order value (i.e. money spent) and not the total number of orders.

One customer could have 2 orders but could have spent £10,000, but another customer could have 100 orders, and only spent £500.

Right now, I have this which gets me the top 10 customers by the number of orders.

```
var customers = (from c in _context.Customers where c.SaleOrders.Count > 0
        let activeCount = c.SaleOrders.Count(so => so.Status != SaleOrderStatus.Cancelled)
        orderby activeCount descending
        select c).Take(10);
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Jon Skeet's comment about doing a double `Sum`, I wrote the following query which compiles.

```
var customers = (from c in _context.Customers where c.SaleOrders.Count > 0
        let orderSum = c.SaleOrders.Where(so => so.Status != SaleOrderStatus.Cancelled)
                                   .Sum(so => so.LineItems.Sum(li => li.CalculateTotal()))
        orderby orderSum descending
        select c).Take(10);
```

But when I run this, I get the following error:

[image: LINQ doesn't recognise method on entity]

It seems LINQ doesn't recognise my `.CalculateTotal()` method which sit on my `LineItem.cs` entity.

Comment: So instead of using `Count` you need to use `Sum` to sum the values of those orders...

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work because the list of `LineItem` entities is what needs to be summed up, no?

Comment: You should show exactly what you tried - chances are you'll need to sum *twice* (once per order, and then once to sum the order totals...)

Comment: Good point, thanks, I'll update the question to show what I tried.

Comment: Your current problem is that CalculateTotal, as you say, isn't recognised as valid linq to sql. I would imagine it is just doing something like `return quantity*value;` - if so just inline this calcluation.

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of these helper methods that make my entities a little smarter. It seems to have worked! :) Please reply as an answer, so that I may mark as answered

Comment: @Ciwan: I'm reluctant to add it as an answer purely because what I said only answered half your question and the more trivial part at that. This website encourages self answers though - you could add an answer yourself detailing the steps you took to resolve your issue.

Comment: Ok will do that, thanks Chris :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you were seeing is that `CalculateTotal()` is not something that Linq can translate into SQL (which is done at run-time, hence no complier error).

The essential problem here is that Linq doesn't really work on lambdas (`Func<>`), but actually Expressions (`Expression<Func<>>`), which is the code in a partial compiled state, which Linq then goes about disassembling and translating into SQL.

So, let assume CalculateTotal is a member function defined like this:

```
 public decimal CalculateTotal()
 {
      return this.quantity * this.value;
 }
```

We could define that as a local lambda function

```
 Func<LineItem, decimal> CalculateTotal = (li => li.quantity * li.value);
```

Now, we have a lambda which takes a LineItem and returns a value, which is exactly what `Sum()` wants, so now we can replace:

```
.Sum(so => so.LineItems.Sum(li => li.CalculateTotal()))
```

with

```
.Sum(so => so.LineItems.Sum(CalculateTotal))
```

But that will crash, just as it did before, because, as I said, it wants an Expression.  So, we give it one:

```
 Expression<Func<LineItem, decimal>> CalculateTotal = (li => li.quantity * li.value);
```